# which is best way multiple sites in same magento install or different magento installation?

Tags: magento

I have six magento site that I need to host on separate domain. so which is best way to install these magento site. Is it better to install all six site in one magento installation by creating stores in admin or its better to install separate magento for all six magento site separately ? what are the pros and cons of both way ? Any one please help with this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to setup multiple storefronts on one Magento installation by following [link](http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/).

Comment: Please don't link to external sites unless it supports content you have already included in your answer.